# Can't connect to Virtualbox web server (using Bridged Network)

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos, apache-http-server, virtual-host

The host is using CentOS 7 (from DVD ISO). I installed Apache (yum install httpd) and made sure the service is running. I've tried restarting the service and the guest machine itself, however I still can't access its IP address (10.0.2.15) from my host machine (Windows 8). I've set Bridge Connection in the settings window as well.

My intention is to use it as a web server for online purposes (and of course be able to access it myself. I'll only have a single website.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is iptables running on your centos machine?   try running iptables -L to see if there are any rules blocking communication.   Can you access the websever from the CentOS install?   are you using some non-standard port (something other than 80 or 443 for https)?    How are you going about starting/restarting apache on the CentOS box?

Comment: You say the guest is supposed to have a bridged interface. 10.0.2.15 is the address that Virtualbox normally uses for NAT network interfaces. Does the guest have more than one virtual network? Did you statically assign an address to the interface within the guest? Is it possible you're mistaken about the interface type assigned to the guest's network? I presume 10.0.2.15 isn't actually a valid address for your local network.

Comment: ah good eye, i should have caught that..

Comment: Sorry for bringing this up again, but I have a similar problem. What am I looking for when I do iptables -L? I see ACCEPT and a few REJECT. However, following this page, I thought I had turned off my firewall completely. http://www.shellhacks.com/en/HowTo-Disable-The-Iptables-Firewall-in-CentOS-RHEL